# Case Statement with different operator in Where Condition

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, switch-statement, where-clause

I am trying to figure out how to have following condition in a SQL Server Store procedure.
I have a parameter of @Variance which can have either 'Y' or 'N' or 'A'

The where condition has to be like:

```
IF @Variance  = 'Y' THEN
 flag_d ≠ ‘Y’ OR  flag_c ≠ ‘Y’

IF @Variance = 'N' THEN
 flag_d = ‘Y’ AND  flag_c = ‘Y’ 

and If @Variance  = 'A' THEN
Do not check columns flag_c and flag_d.
```

flag_c and flag_d can have following values 'Y','N','X' or it can be blank.

Is there a way i can achieve this without using dynamic sql.

Comment: Are you trying to filter by this condition, or putting out different info based on this condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple `Or` statement in the `Where` clause:

```
Where   (@Variance = 'Y' And (Flag_D <> 'Y' Or Flag_C <> 'Y'))
Or      (@Variance = 'N' And (Flag_D = 'Y' And Flag_C = 'Y'))
Or      (@Variance = 'A')
```

Comment: the second condition should use `AND` instead of `OR`

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might help you get started:

```
CASE
WHEN @Variance = 'Y' THEN outcome
WHEN @Variance = 'N' THEN outcome
WHEN @Variance = 'A' THEN outcome
ELSE something
END
```

or if you need Y, N, and A to all do different things then do multiple cases:

```
CASE
WHEN @Variance = 'Y' THEN outcome1
END,
CASE
WHEN @Variance = 'N' THEN outcome2
END,
CASE
WHEN @Variance = 'A' THEN outcome3
END
```

Comment: you haven't taken the other fields into consideration - doesn't answer the question.